# Google OpenID suddenly not working?

Tags: bug, openid, google-openid

Returning to electronics.stackexchange.com, I was greeted with a logged-out menu bar.
I tried to log in again, using my Google / gmail OpenID, but it just wanted to create/link a new account for me. It did not recognize my stack exchange links at all.

However, when going to meta.stackexchange.com, this login works, and it would show my three other stack exchange associations.

Wish I could provide more bug reproduction information, but sadly not.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache and logging in again.